# What is different between "Remember me functionality" and 'Keep me logged in" functionality?

Tags: java

I want my website to have a `checkbox` that users can click so that they will not have to log in each time they visit my website.

Comment: They're two names for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

## Remember me

Remember-me authentication refers to websites being able to remember the identity of a principal between sessions. This is typically accomplished by sending a cookie to the browser, with the cookie being detected during future sessions and causing automated login to take place. Spring Security provides the necessary hooks for these operations to take place and has two concrete remember-me implementations. One uses hashing to preserve the security of cookie-based tokens and the other uses a database or other persistent storage mechanism to store the generated tokens.

### Keep me logged in

When checked, the option Keep me logged in allows you to force your browser to remember your credentials to be automatically connected when reaching the login page. By default, your credentials are stored for 2 weeks. After this period, you will have to log in again.